# How to load JSON data into span of HTML while loading the page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have following html code. It has inline data-value as 12500

```
<div class="number">
   <span id="count" data-counter="counterup" data-value="12500">0</span>
</div>
```

I would want it to get it updated with value fetched from JSON.
My script file looks like this

```
url = "../assets/pages/data.json";
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON(url,function(setData){
  var tsCounter = document.querySelector('#count');
  tsCounter.dataset.value = setData[1].count;
});
)};
```

What I see is, this value is updated after DOM is created and that is the reason I don't see it on page load. I don't want to use "onload" event of HTML's body.

Is there anyway I can get this working?

Comment: You want to update the DOM before it's created? :)

Comment: Why don't you load the data while rendering the page? Otherwise you'd have to block the whole rendering and use syncronous JavaScript. This is somehow not what ajax (async by purpose) is designed for.